# ¿Como soluciono este problema de descarga de OCR: I/Vision: libocr.so library load status: false?

Tags: android, google-api, ocr

Tengo un este problema con la api OCR mobil vision text google: Creo que no descarga la dependencia de OCR me sale el siguiente mensaje:

> /SendBroadcastPermission:
>   action:android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
>   mPermissionType:0 E/HW-JPEG-DEC: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete:
>   HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null E/HW-JPEG-DEC:
>   HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: HME_JPEG_DEC_Delete: decoder_ctx=null
>   W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for
>   com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found. I/DynamiteModule:
>   Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and
>   remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:1702
>   I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of
>   com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 1702 I/Vision:
>   Loading library libocr.so I/Vision: libocr.so library load status:
>   false W/hwaps: APS: null pointer in reset Application terminated.

Estoy utilizando la version :    `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.0'`

Comment: Sería necesario que adjuntaras el xml, dado que el error que publicas suele estar en el ya mencionado xml.

Comment: La app funciona bien en  celular kyocera con android 5.1  y cuando trato de  usarla en un huawei p9 lite 2017 con android 7.0  no descarga la dependencia library libocr.so   el huawei al igual que el kyocera tiene todos los permisos

Comment: parece entonces que es un problema con el SDK, puede ser que la libreria no admita un SDK mayor